# How to pass instance variables via attributes in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to pass the instance variable, jsonString, of ComponentA to CustomElement:

```
<CustomElement jsonFilters="{{jsonString}}"></CustomElement>
```

Currently, the value mapped from jsonFilters is empty/null. What is the correct way to pass a string to a custom element? Any help much appreciated

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 this should be

```
<CustomElement [jsonFilters]="jsonString"></CustomElement>
```

and this is property binding not attribute binding. Attributes only support strings not objects.

Comment: Ah thanks, will give that a go on Monday :) I'm assuming it'll be the same with AngularDart?

Comment: Angular.dart (1.x) uses a different syntax. I don't remember though. It's quite some time I used it. Angular2 (Dart, TS, JS) use the syntax demonstrated in my answer.